Paramiko - How to read SSH server output of a script ran at logon
I am writing a script to do some automation and searching through the Paramiko documentation and Stackoverflow I cannot find a way to do this.
When logging in to the server in question, the server runs a logon script and asks the user for input. I need to be able to read the data sent by the server and respond with the correct user input to move the script along. Since the script runs at logon instead of as the result of entering some command, I obviously cannot use SSHClient.exec_command(). Is there a way to read the data sent by the SSH server immediately after calling SSHClient.connect()?

Please [edit] your question to describe specifically what triggers this script to run when you login. Does it run from your .bashrc file or something similar to that? It might be helpful to run the ssh command-line utility to connect to this server and show the script starting and prompting you for input. Include the ssh "-vv" option to print debugging output, then [edit] your question to include the debugging output along with the script output.

Please provide more details so others can help you. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You might want to look into the pexpect package.

After reading the documentation, I'd guess for something like this, after reading the documentation for Paramiko, you should use the Channel directly, and use .recv() to receive what the server messages, and .send() to send your response.
The .connect() method for the Client seems to allow you to pass in a socket, which can be a channel. Perhaps you can manipulate it from there.
Otherwise, since Client wraps Channel and Transport, it might be best to look at the source code and how it's implemented to put in the specific things you need.

I am trying to follow along but that doesn't seem to be getting me any closer. I tried:
cs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cs.connect((ip, port))
t = paramiko.transport.Transport(cs)
c = paramiko.channel.Channel(t)
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.connect(ip, port, username, password, sock=c)
When s.connect() is called, it never returns. Also it feels kind of redundant to call s.connect() when I already have a socket connected to the host.

Looking at the source code for connect(),
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/51eb55debf2ebfe56f38378005439a029a48225f/paramiko/client.py#L217
The steps are as follows:

A socket is created.
A Transport is created based on the socket and encryption keys,
Then it authenticates using some standard method.
You can probably do one of two things:
Copy what connect is doing before auth.
Subclass  AuthStrategy, overriding the authenticate() method.
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/51eb55debf2ebfe56f38378005439a029a48225f/paramiko/client.py#L217

